# Win2K8 R2 Hyper-V : Cannot access Hyper-V Manager from remote PC in same LAN & Domain

Tags: hyper-v, windows-server-2008-r2, remote

I have a Physical Win2K8 R2 server GUI w/ Hyper-V. I have DC/AD setup (as a virtual inside this physical). I can log in to Physical Server using a DOMAIN USER ACCOUNT, then open Hyper-V manager, access the virtual machines. Before accessing virtual machine, I have to enter username/password.

In another physical PC I have Win7 Ultimate w/Hyper-V manager. This PC is also under same domain and LAN. I log in to this PC using same Domain User account. I open Hyper-V manager and

> try to connect to the Physical Win2K8
>   server. I get permission error: Yo do
>   not have the permission to complete
>   this task. Contact administrator ...
>   .. .

I used to able to access the Hyper-V from this Win7 machine earlier. Few days ago, my DC crashed (which is a virtual, inside Physical Win2K8). Had lot of trouble to get physical pc and virtuals to get back online. My guess is, while there was no DC (week & half) and revived from a secondary (old) DC/AD, some permission got screwd.

I have done: mmc.exe -> add/rmvSnapIn->AuthMngr->BrowseAuthStoreXmlFile->Admin_>Add and Added Domain Users as Admin of Hyper-V. Before doing this, I could not access Hyper-V manager even from the physical machine.

Do I have to uninstall/re-install Hyper-V manager in Win7 machine? Why same user account can access Hyper-V manager from local machine, but not from a remote machine?

I will appreciate a reply. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Followed instructions in this link and it worked.

http://www.ms4u.info/2009/09/remote-management-hyper-v.html